# this.setState not updating nested array in user object, but when console.loging the same logic, it returns a correct looking object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, the user can have a bunch of meals selected. I have an array of objects inside the user object to store the meals.

After the user selects some meals and clicks submit, I use setState to try and update the user meals, I do it like this.

```
submitAllMeals(arrayOfMeals) {
    this.setState({
        user: {
            ...this.state.user,
            meals: [...this.state.user.meals, ...arrayOfMeals]
        }
    });

    console.log({
        user: {
            ...this.state.user,
            meals: [...this.state.user.meals, ...arrayOfMeals]
        }
    });

    axios
        .put('http://localhost:5000/getuserdata', {
            userdata: this.state.user
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

The strange thing is that the meals are not added to the user object in the state, but the console log below logs the correct output.

Is there a reason my state is not updating even though the logic to make the new object is correct? If so, anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**React's `setState` is async,** which means `this.state` may be updated after you consume the component's internal state. You have to think of that as a **request** – it doesn't happen right away.

At the point of your `axios` request, you can't still be sure you'll have `this.state.user`.

To solve this, you can use a callback. The second argument of `setState` receives a callback, so you can do your `axios` request that consumes the updated state there, e.g.:

```
this.setState({
    user: {}
}, () => {
    // your request that uses the updated this.state.user
});
```

`setState()` documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

React docs has this little bit explaining it all

> Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Besides that React's `setState` can have a callback part which goes after the actual state declarations and is executed just after changes to state(let's just call it like that for simplicity) happens. This is what I would advise you - to put the actual request as a callback of the `setState` thus you will definitely send updated data:

```
submitAllMeals(arrayOfMeals) {
 this.setState({
    user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        meals: [...this.state.user.meals, ...arrayOfMeals]
    }},
    axios
      .put('http://localhost:5000/getuserdata', {
          userdata: this.state.user
      })
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
      });
 );

 console.log({
    user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        meals: [...this.state.user.meals, ...arrayOfMeals]
    }
 });
}
```

[Here are the docs explaining React's setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)